# Select along with count in one request using Linq to Entities

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, linq-to-entities

Lets say I have two API methods for getting total items count and part of the items for some page. Is there a way to merge these methods and get total count if needed and some part of these items in one request?

```
public async Task<SomeView[]> Get(SomeViewFilter filter, int skip, int take)
{
    using var db = dbContext();
    return await db
     .SomeTable()
     .Filter(filter)
     .Skip(skip)
     .Take(take)
     .ToArrayAsync();
}

public async Task<int> Count(SomeViewFilter filter)
{
    using var db = dbContext();
    return await db
     .SomeTable()
     .Filter(filter)
     .CountAsync();
}
```

Comment: hi i didn't say if what your're trying it's clear for me. You whant a function (Get) that can take all elements or take just some  part it's ok ?

Comment: Here is an article about batching queries with EF and Linq. No idea if it works or is applicable for your case:
https://www.tabsoverspaces.com/232079-multiquery-more-queries-in-one-batch-in-entity-framework-using-linq

Comment: @JonasH looks like a heavy overkill, i wanna know if there is some out of the box solution and make it in one request

Comment: @Sanpas a want to get some elements with total count of the elements in db in one linq to entity request

Answer (score 0):

After merging, `skip` and `take` will become optional parameters, so give them a default value such as `-100` (this is used to distinguish which judgment to enter)

Then change the return type of the method to **`object`**, indicating that the method can return different type of data.

```
public async Task<object> Get(SomeViewFilter filter, int skip = -100, int take = -100)
    {
        using var db = dbContext();
        if (skip == -100 && take == -100)
        {
              return await db
                        .SomeTable()
                        .Filter(filter)
                        .CountAsync();
        }
        else
        {
               return await db
                        .SomeTable()
                        .Filter(filter)
                        .Skip(skip)
                        .Take(take)
                        .ToArrayAsync().
        } 
    }
```